# gltf export UV Map node not working

Tags: uv

I don't if this usually doesn't work or if I am just missing something but:

I want to export an object with a uv unwrapped material as gltf. The UV Map I am using is the second one shown in the UV Maps panel.
When exporting is it using the first UVMap (UVMap) and not the one I selected in the UV Map node (export)

[image]

Comment: take a look at the camera icon right of export?It seems unselected.

Comment: @NatureK that unfortunately doesn't change anything.

Comment: or maybe you don't set the second UV,you just creat it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls make a gif to show what you do,or upload your profile.Mine is worked.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you select the uvmap.001 in your uv map node and then export it as an gltf file, will it export the uvmap or uvmap.001?
For me it is always exporting the uvmap instead of the selected uvmap.001. Thats what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yes,the output is different.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-y1TAOtzMST
I created a simple test file. For me it is not working.

Comment: it's also work to me, I just use the image I have because I don't have your image.And I also use the profile you give and change nothing, it shows as last 2 picture, that's all right,maybe you need to make a small gif to show...Btw,I use blender 3.1

Comment: Thank you for your time!
it works for me as well now. I was using paint3D to preview. In order to eliminate paint as a source of mistake I also used this preview website https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ but in both cases the file is not previewed correctly. Strange behavior.